# TK 103 data format

Tags: gps, device

I am trying to decode the Hex data sent by the device to my server. I am able parse the latitude , longitude ,speed etc. But what I am unable to decode is the 'state' information. I believe they represent the state of the vehicle e.g. oil and electricity, ignition on/off etc.

I cant find any document which can guide me as to how to decode the 8 bits of state and what each bit represents.

Any help or documentation for the same will be appreciated.

Comment: If you take some minutes of time (I needed 5 seconds) although i don't know the TK103, then you should see, that the TK103 is a GPS tracker, and has no connection to oil state. state is probably the GPS state, just make yourself a bit more familar with GPS. read the NMEA 103, there you find info what could mean state. But you finnaly cannot know without having a format description  / ask the manufacturer.

Comment: HI ,I do know what TK103 is.I have been working on GPS protocols for days now and not just TK103 but others like TK102, GT02 and GT06 also. It does send information such as oil and elctricity connected, Ignition on/off, power on/off along with the regular GPS data. I ve already found the solution to it in one of the documentations. There are 8 bits of state information that the device sends in addition to GPS data, every bit indicates somethings. I only needed that pattern to decode the Hex data that i was getting. May be you should have spent a little more than 5 Seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I have been able to find out.

8 bits of IO:
First bit represents Power : 0 indicating on, 1 indicating off
Second bit represents Ignition status: 1 indicating ACC on, 0 indicating ACC off.
Other reservations.

Source: http://www.traccar.org/docs/protocol.jsp

Answer (score 0):

Probably state is related to Valid / Invalid position.
Try it out, by comparing the value when having GPS free view to sky, and without (disabel Antenna, shield with metall paper trash bin or metall foil.

Comment: Valid/ Invalid state comes as a separate bit. These are I/O state bits that I am talking about

Answer (score 0):

If this may help, I just release a new server base on a jison grammar to make protocol easier to implement. https://www.npmjs.org/package/gpsdtracking